# The xml files are not compiled into classes folder in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a maven project which has many modules, I imported it to my Intellij as a maven project.

In the project settings, I changed the Project compiler output to `xxx/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`, the absolute path of my project. And also, I changed the Compiler output of all the other modules to this location. But when I check the classes folder at this location, I found two things which I think are not right:

1. The xml files are not compiled into the related path under the
   *classes* folder, which are under the java folder instead of the
   resource folder in source code.
2. There's a `production` folder under the *classes* folder, the classes
   of other modules in it as the path they should be.

I'd be appreciated if anyone can help me understand this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following changes:

1. Your project compiler output folder should not follow the WAR standard.  Make it /target, separate for all your artifacts.  IntelliJ will create a /production and /test folder and put the .class files there.
2. Your XML files should be under /resources in the Maven convention.
3. You need to create an artifact for your deployment.  That is where the WAR standard comes into play.

If you follow the conventions correctly IntelliJ will build and run your application perfectly.

Comment: Thanks dyffymo. That's how I usually do. But I can do nothing except getting it work. I'm wondering why the compiler output is not working after I specified it?

Comment: Put the resources into that directory manually when you create the artifact.  Compiling and creating the artifact are not the same thing.

Comment: Of course you can do something.  That's your choice.  Try my changes, see if it works.  If it does, keep the changes.  If not, blow away the local copy, check out a clean local from the repository, and try again.

Comment: I see.  I will try this out later, maybe tomorrow, cus I don't have my lap aside. Thank you, duffymo.

Comment: Can't it be working with maven configured correctly? I didn't get what you said creating the artifact.

Comment: I think that's the problem.  Compiling and creating the artifact/package (e.g. JAR, WAR, or EAR) are separate matters.  What's in your artifact?

Comment: Only one of the modules of web with `WEB-INF`.